# How to avoid sql connection close if thousands of Goroutine try to access the database

Tags: go

I have a chapter table have about 2000000 rows, I want to to update each row for some specific conditions:

```
func main(){
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM chapters where title = 'custom_type'")
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        _ = rows.Scan(&id)
        fmt.Println(id)
        go updateRowForSomeReason(id)
    }
}

func updateRowForSomeReason(id int) {
    row, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT id FROM chapters where parent_id = %v", id))  
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)  <----- // here is the panic occurs 
    }
    for rows.Next() {
       // ignore update code for simplify
    }
}
```

Inside `updateRowForSomeReason`, I execute update statement for each row.

It will works with few seconds, after that the error will print:

```
323005 
323057 
323125 
323244 
323282 
323342 
323459 
323498 
323556 
323618 
323693 
325343 
325424 
325468 
325624 
325816 
326001 
326045 
326082 
326226 
326297 
panic: sql: database is closed
```

Comment: How are you executing the update statement? Please include that code. And keep in mind that you should not ignore errors and you should close `rows` after you're done with them. Also I'm curious to know how many is 20W.

Comment: ... additionally if the actual code is executed in `main` just like in the question, then you need to synchronize your goroutines... This is becuase after the `for rows.Next() {` loop is done, `main` will exit and it will *not* wait for any `updateRowForSomeReason` executing goroutines that haven't yet finished their job effectively killing them mid-process.

Comment: @TangMonk please make sure, when providing code in the question, that that code is as close as possible to your actual code, the ideal would be that the code in question can be used to reproduce the error, otherwise we will be here all day pointing out what's wrong with the code in the question while your actual code has a completely different problem. In `updateRowForSomeReason` you're discarding rows with `_, err := db.Query` but on the next line after the error checking you have `for rows.Next() {`... so which is it? are you keeping the rows or are you discarding them?

Comment: @mkopriva, sorry, I simplified code for easily reading with careless

Comment: the `*sql.Rows` object returned from `db.Query` needs to be [closed](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Rows.Close) after work with it is done. The idiomatic way to do this is after your check the error returned from Query you add the statement `defer rows.Close()`. See https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_Query_multipleResultSets and https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#example_DB_QueryContext

Comment: @mkopriva, really thanks for you advice, I tried to add `select {}` to end of `main()` function for avoid program terminate halfway, the `database is closed` error disappeared

Comment: What is the UPDATE statement doing? You could be running out of resources, since you're working with potentially very large result sets and doing nested queries in program memory.

Comment: This seems likely due to not closing results.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't seem to be a Go problem as such, more a question of how to optimally structure your SQL within your code. You're taking a result set from executing a query on 2,000,000 rows:

```
rows, err := db.Query("SELECT id FROM chapters where title = 'custom_type'")
```

then executing another query *for each row* in this result set:

```
row, err := db.Query(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT id FROM chapters where parent_id = %v", id))
```

and then executing some more code *for each of those*, apparently one by one:

```
for rows.Next() {
   // ignore update code for simplify
}
```

This is effectively two levels of nesting of statements, which is very inefficient way to load all these results into program memory and then execute independent UPDATE statements:

```
SELECT
     +---->SELECT
                +---->UPDATE
```

Instead, you could be doing all the work in the database itself, which would be much more efficient. You don't show what the `UPDATE` statement is, but this is the key part. Let's say you want to set a `publish` flag. You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE chapters
    SET publish=true
    WHERE parent_id in
        (SELECT id FROM chapters
         WHERE title='custom_type')
    RETURNING id;
```

By using a nested query, you can combine *all* of the three separate queries into one single query. The database has all the information it needs to optimise the operation and build the most efficient query plan, and you are only executing a **single** `db.Query` operation. The `RETURNING` clause lets you retrieve a list of the ids that ended up being updated in the operation. So the code would be as simple as:

```
func main(){
    rows, err := db.Query("UPDATE chapters SET publish=true WHERE parent_id in" +
                          "(SELECT id FROM chapters WHERE title='custom_type')" +
                          "RETURNING id;")
    if err != nil {
       panic(err)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        var id int
        _ = rows.Scan(&id)
        fmt.Println(id)
    }
}
```